# Cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks without use useEffect, must be in handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this error, I have already searched tirelessly for different solutions through various internet pages including stackoverflow and I cannot find one that applies to my case,

I will summarize as much as possible so as not to expand the topic too much and go straight to the point, I just hope to find someone who can help me

I use a Stepper library to sequence the steps

- In step 1: I confirm the purchase
- In step 2: I choose the payment method in this case only card
- In step 3: I fill in the card details to create the payment with a
  library called Stripe that allows payments with credit or debit cards
- In step 4: It is the final step that will be shown only when the
  payment has been completely made

The problem is that in step 3 to create the payment method with code extracted from the Stripe documentation, asynchronous calls are used with await and this is the one that generates the error, when I go to step 4 I show a new component and I disappear the components of step 3 ,, when I do this I receive the error that I am trying to update a status in a component that no longer exists, however at the moment I update my Stepper status to take me to the last step ,, I I don't do any more status updates, and still I get the message and saw that what is causing this problem is the await call and it asks me to clean up all the subscriptions and asynchronous tasks before moving to a new component, so I need to know How do I clean this asynchronous call?

In step 3 It should be said that the entire process of validating the fields of the card data form and when the payment method begins to be created, it is done in a handleSubmit function called by a button ,,, that's why that the solution or asynchronous call using the useEffect is not applicable for my case, I need a way to clean everything directly in the same handleSubmit

Here I leave my summarized code:

global state constant, right here I create my Stepper state:

```html
here delete code of several state variables, just leave the state variables of the stepper when state change updating on a number


const useStateGlobal = () => {
    const [steps] = useState(
        [{
            title: 'Confirmar Compra',
            href: 'http://example1.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 1)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Seleccionar tipo de pago',
            href: 'http://example2.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 2)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Detalles de pago',
            href: 'http://example3.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 3)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Compra Finalizada',
            href: 'http://example4.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 4)
            }
        }]
    );

    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);
   
    return {
        steps,
        currentStep,setCurrentStep
    }
};
```

Now this is the Stepper component:

```html
export const Confirmar_Paquete_Stepper = () => {  
        
        const { steps, currentStep, setCurrentStep } = useBetween(useStateGlobal);
        const buttonStyle = { background: '#E0E0E0', width: 200, padding: 16, textAlign: 'center', 
        margin: '0 auto', marginTop: 32 };

        const onClickNext = (e) => {           
            let valor = (currentStep == null || currentStep == 0 )  ? 1 : currentStep+1;           
            setCurrentStep(valor);
        }

         const onClickBack = (e) => {
             let valor = (currentStep == null || currentStep == 0) ? 1 : currentStep - 1;
             setCurrentStep(valor);
         }

        if (currentStep == 0) {
        return (           
               <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete"> 
                   <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />
                <Confirmar_Paquete />
               </div>
        );
        }
        else if (currentStep == 1) {
        return (
               <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
                   <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep} />
                   <Seleccionar_Tipo_Pago_Paquete />     
                <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
               </div>
        );
        } else if (currentStep == 2) {
            return (
                <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
                    <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />

                  these are the components that create the inputs of the card number, expiration 
                  date, cvc and process and create the card payment method with the Stripe library

                    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                        <CheckoutForm2/>
                    </Elements>
                    <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
                </div>
        );
        }   
          else if (currentStep == 3) {
              return (
                  <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
          
                      <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />
                      <Finalizar_Compra_Paquete />
                      <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
                  </div>
            );
        }  
};
```

Now the CheckoutForm2 component

```html
 const CheckoutForm2 = () => {    
    const { steps, currentStep, setCurrentStep, token, datos_paquete_seleccionado, setDatos_paquete_seleccionado, camposDatosTarjeta, setcamposDatosTarjeta, formErrors, setformErrors, errores_servTarjeta, seterrores_servTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta,
        paseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta
       } = useBetween(useStateGlobal);
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const titularTarjetaRegex = RegExp(
        /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/
    );
    const emailRegex = RegExp(
        /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
    );
    const codigopostalTarjetaRegex = RegExp(
        /^[0-9]+$/
    );
    const ciudadTarjetaRegex = RegExp(
        /^[A-Za-z]+$/
    );

    
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            
        };
    }, []);

    const HandleValidar = async (event) => {
          Here I have code only to validate the form fields by OnChange, I have deleted it because they 
          are not important
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
       
        event.preventDefault();        
        const { titular_tarjeta, correo_tarjeta, ciudad_tarjeta, codigo_postal_tarjeta } = event.target;  
        
Here I leave only an example of how valid each field of my form when I click directly on handleSubmit by onClick,

        //TITULAR TARJETA
        if (titular_tarjeta.value.length < 3) {           
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Ingrese mínimo 3 caracteres"
         }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");            
        }
        else if (!titularTarjetaRegex.test(titular_tarjeta.value)) {            
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Formato de nombres inválido" 
         }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");
            
        }
        else if (titular_tarjeta.value.length > 22) {
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Ingrese maximo 22 caracteres" 
        }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");
        }
        else {
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("SI");            
        }

        

        if (!stripe || !elements) {
            // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
            // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
            return;
        }
        
        Here I validate through a set of each state that all the fields have been completed and validated 
        correctly to just start creating the payment


        if (paseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta == "SI")
        {    
            const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);

            const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: {
                    email: camposDatosTarjeta.correo_tarjeta,
                    name: camposDatosTarjeta.titular_tarjeta,
                    address: {
                        city: camposDatosTarjeta.ciudad_tarjeta,
                        country: 'PE',
                        postal_code: camposDatosTarjeta.codigo_postal_tarjeta,
                    }
                },               
            });

            if (error) {                
            } 
            else 
            {     

This is where the moment I update the Stepper to number 3, which would be the last step ,, is when the error appears ,,,
the one that causes this error is the await ,,, since if I delete all that code above the await stripe the error does not appear anymore ,,, then I want to know how to clean the asynchronous tasks before moving to a new component, everything must be performed in my function by handlesubmit
     
               setCurrentStep(3);                   
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div id="contenedor-detalles-tarjeta">
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="md" justify="center">
                <label className="detalles-tarjeta-titulo">
                <Typography >
                    <span >Detalles de tarjeta</span>
                </Typography>
            </label>
            <form id="realizar-pago-visa" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>

           Here I have deleted all the code of the creation of the fields of the payment form, I have 
           only left the handleSubmit button

         <Button type="submit" className="confirmar-orden" name="confirmar_orden" disabled= 
         {!stripe} variant="contained" color="primary">Confirmar orden</Button> 
         </form>
         </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

- 0 is step 1
- 1 is step 2
- 2 is step 3
- 3 is step 4

as you can see, with setCurrentStep (3); I go to the last step of the Stepper that would be the final component and I disappear the Element components and the CheckoutForm2 that are from the previous step, that is where I receive the error because of the await stripe.createPaymentMethod ({... and it says that I am trying to update a state in a component that no longer exists, however when setCurrentStep (3) occurs; I no longer update anything else and I don't understand why I receive the error, so I think the error refers to await and asks that I also clean the Asynchronous await task and I don't know how to do it, I must clean everything through the same handleSubmit, without using useEffect since for my case that doesn't apply.

I will finally leave a picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJrO7.png)